# How can I use tcp/ip in Matlab that is supported by Coder?

Tags: c, matlab, tcp

A project I am working on uses algorithms written in MatLab that need to be converted to C for use in an RTOS. We need to use TCP/IP, but the tcpip object in MatLab isn't supported by Coder (which converts MatLab code to C code). Is there a work around or way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can incorporate networking C code into the Matlab code, and then covert it using coder.

You can use either coder.ceval([function]) or call a MEX file that wraps the c code.